# Is Astral projection evil?

Tags: spiritual-level, body

Can anyone advise if in any scripture it is mentioned that Astral projection is evil?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83517/discussion-on-question-by-ram-is-astral-projection-evil).

Comment: what do you mean by astral projection? Unclear what you are asking about.....

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Astral projection is subtle body and not atma coming out of physical body and travelling on any place on earth. Can be done by anyone, no need to be spiritually advanced, you can check many videos in YouTube and Google for this. Mastering the technique may take few days, but it is easy.

Comment: Problem is what happens if some other astral being who is in search of gross body enters your body when you leave? It's definitely a risk

Comment: @AkshayKumarS another Astral being can't enter in someone else's body who is doing Astral projection. Because we don't have the touch sensation...maybe if some other type of being may enter...that I don't know. But not the normal human beings who are doing Astral projection

Comment: When I say astral, its not astral being directly.  Am asking you some human who has faced unnatural death and is astrally roaming looking for gross body. So what happens then if you leave your gross body?

Comment: @AkshayKumarS if atma is roaming, then I don't know what can it do. When Living beings do Astral, only subtle body comes out not the complete atma, a slight disturbance or lack of concentration can stop Astral projection and the subtle body at once comes backs in physical body..I hope I have answered Ur query.

Comment: 'astral' and 'astral projection' are 'new age' terms. They are not terms used in the Vedanta.

Answer (score 1):

Doing things not sanctioned by shastras is a recipe for trouble. Please consider Bhagavan Krishna's advice from Bhagavad Gita

> yaḥ śāstra-vidhim utsṛjya vartate kāma-kārataḥ
>   na sa siddhim avāpnoti na sukhaṁ na parāṁ gatim
>
> He who discards scriptural injunctions and acts according to his own whims attains neither perfection, nor happiness, nor the supreme destination. [[Bhagavad Gita 16.23](https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/16/23)]

Comment: Hello! Welcome to [hinduism.se] Can you explain why asral projection is not sanctioned by scriptures?

Comment: There are numerous injunctions on what is best for us in the Gita itself. It is certainly not a sattvic idea to say the least.

Comment: @subashrajaa AFAIK Astral projection is not mentioned in scriptures. But I guess someone might have more knowledge regarding this....

Comment: The abilities to go outside the physical body are related in Patanjali's Yoga Aphorisms. It can be done only by very advanced yogis. To try and do so without the proper yogic disciplines only leads to disaster. Those who supposedly 'teach' these techniques on youtube or anywhere on the internet are simply the blind leading the blind...

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda can you please put Patanjali's yoga Aphorisms in your answer and also the warning that it should be only done by advanced yogis..